# 401 Unauthorized error while trying to create shared Google App Contact

Tags: google-api, gdata, google-contacts-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to create a new contact using GData .Net Api.
I've got an AccessToken using the newer Google.Apis.

This acces token works alright to get,update and delete contacts, but if I try to create one I receive a 401 Unauthorized response.

This is the code I use to add my contact :

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullName))
        {
            FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullName))
            {
                ThrowTerminatingError(new ErrorRecord(
                    new ArgumentException("Please provide a name for the contact"),
                    null, ErrorCategory.InvalidArgument, null));
            }
        }

        Contact = new Contact
        {
            Name = new Name
            {
                GivenName = FirstName,
                FamilyName = LastName,
                FullName = FullName
            },
            Content = "Notes",                    
        };

        foreach (var m in Emails)
        {
            Contact.Emails.Add(new EMail(m));
        }
        RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings(applicationName, AuthentParameters);
        ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);

        var feedUri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}{1}/full/", Scope, Domain));
        cr.Insert(feedUri, Contact));
```

The following atom feed is sent using POST method to http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/(my domain)/full/  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <gd:name>
    <gd:givenName>Guillaume</gd:givenName>
    <gd:familyName>Davion</gd:familyName>
    <gd:fullName>Guillaume Davion</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>
  <gd:email address="gudavion@test.info" />
  <category term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" />
  <content type="text">Notes</content>
</entry>
```

Headers are :

- Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
- Authorization: Bearer ya29.(access token)
- GData-Version: 3.0

Thanks to anyone who could help me.

Comment: what scope did you send when you authenticated?

Comment: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with two things : 
First, changing the way I construct the feed uri :

```
var feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri(Domain));
```

And second adding a label to the email :

```
Contact.Emails.Add(new EMail(m) { Label = "Default" });
```

With this, the add goes smoothly.